# On voting of suspended user, votes to the answer shows 0

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, account-suspension

Suppose a answer has 3 votes. As we know suspended user can not vote. But if suspended user votes for the answer, **Suspended user can not vote** message is displayed and votes to that answer becomes 0. Is it a bug or there is logic behind this???

Comment: If you can post example (link to such answer and screenshot of what you see) it might help to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd You'd have to get yourself suspended to reproduce that behaviour ;)

Comment: Actully it does not become 0, but it displays 0 at that time. After I refresh It is shown with votes

Comment: Sounds like a bug. @Yannis I can't, but mod or dev probably can - they most likely have special "dummy" accounts exactly for such needs. :-)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Now that I think of it, I can suspend myself, check the bug out and then revoke the suspension, but that would annoy quite a few people and only good it would do would be to verify the behaviour. So this one should be left to the devs.

Comment: @YannisRizos cool, noticed just now you have the Diamond Power on programmers - are you sure that the suspension won't kill your mod tools as well though? Better ask a diamond buddy to do that... ;)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd It probably won't, but I won't risk it. Promise I'll suspend myself as my final act when I ragequit. ;P

Comment: @Yannis fair enough! What about pinging a dev? No such option for a moderator?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Posting a Meta question with the [bug] tag is the fastest way to get a dev's attention... We mods ping devs in chat, nothing special there, the only difference being that we ping them in the Teacher's Lounge. They tend to check in there more often than on other chat rooms, but a Meta [bug] is still the better option.

Comment: Like I said - screenshot raise the chances for attention..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was actually fixed last week, but not because it affected suspended users...it affected another a anonymous case as well.  Honestly, we wouldn't spend that much time on issues specifically affecting suspended users, but since this possibly impacted other users I took a look.